# how to get notification when people post a comment using facebook comment plugin

Tags: facebook, comments

I have created a static webpage and have included facebook comment plugin.

A person commented but i did not receive any notification in facebook or in my email.

What should i do to get notifications to my email when people post using facebook comment?

do i have to do something like this

```
FB.subscribe('comment.create', function(response){

    //make an ajax request to a server side script
    // and in that i can send a mail to my email... isn't it?
    }
});
```

since that page is totally html i dont want to use any more javascripts yet if needed then i will have to use.

so is that the way to notify myself when an  user posts a comment using the facebook comment plugin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the official documentation (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) it says in the FAQ part:

> How do I know when someone comments on my site?
>
> You can subscribe to the 'comment.create' and 'comment.remove' events
> through FB.Event.subscribe.

so yes, you will need to use this method to be notified on comments.

Comment: i asked will facebook do that by default instead of us doing it? i hope they are not... that is the reason we have this create event... ins' it? 

Besides you have said that i will need to use this method to be notified... hope you meant the ajax call ... isn't it? else i had already asked in my question...

Comment: That's facebooks way of notifying you on comments, they supply you with the option to subscribe to events. Once the event fires though, it is up to you to decide what you want to do with it. But yes, using ajax to update your server seems like the right way to go about this.

Comment: could you provide an example code of how to do this? I would like to add it to my drupal site and I don't know which file to put the code in.